# CSS based banner image swap triggered by text mouseover

Tags: html, css, image, mouseover, swap

I'm looking to replace an image background on a banner above my navigation bar with a specific image for each menu item when the user rolls over the menu text.

I want it so that each menu item causes the banner to swap the background for an image related to the text of each menu item.

I only want to use CSS... Not JavaScript.

This seems like the closest thing I could find through some googling, but as you can see, it's a bit different from what I'm looking for:

```html
<div class="nav">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="logo.gif" width="187" height="136" alt="" />
    </a>
</div>
```

And the CSS to go along with it:

```css
div.nav {
    height: 187px;
    width: 136px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url("logo-red.gif");
}

div.nav a, div.nav a:link, div.nav a:visited {
    display: block;
}

div.nav img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
}

div.nav a:hover img {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: what's with the dots in between everything?

Comment: It wouldn't let me post it with img selectors.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it this way. This should accomplish what you're seeking. Others in the community might have a better method, but this is one I've found that works.  Styling the elements, etc. is on you  :)

My jsFiddle for it is located here:
    http://jsfiddle.net/ChadR/tM2Nr/

Either download and host this library, or add it between your head tags.
    https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js

HTML:

```
<div class="HeaderBanner">
    <img id="backBanner"
         src="http://images3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110210142733/recipes/images/thumb/d/db/Packham_pear.jpg/300px-Packham_pear.jpg"
         data-original="http://images3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110210142733/recipes/images/thumb/d/db/Packham_pear.jpg/300px-Packham_pear.jpg" 
         alt="e.s.t" />
</div><!--HeaderBanner-->

<ul id="BannerBar" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
    <li id="button1" data-img="http://watchpeoplejump.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/banana.jpeg?w=300&h=226"><a href="bio.html">Biography</a></li>
    <li id="button2" data-img="http://www.nyapplecountry.com/images/photosvarieties/redrome04.jpg"><a href="#">Albums</a></li>
    <li id="button3"><a href="#">Links</a></li>       
</ul><!--MenuBarHorizontal-->
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#BannerBar li").mouseover(function() {
        $("#backBanner").attr("src", $(this).data("img"));
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $("#backBanner").attr("src", $("#backBanner").data("original"));
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.HeaderBanner {  }
.HeaderBanner img {
height:250px;
}
.MenuBarHorizontal ul { display:block; width:800px; margin:15px auto 15px; }
.MenuBarHorizontal li {
float:left;
margin:0 2px 0 0;
list-style:none;
list-style-image:none;
}
.MenuBarHorizontal li a {
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
color:#000000;
width:150px;
background:#9C0;
text-align:center;
font-weight:bold;
padding:7px 0 7px 0;
}
.MenuBarHorizontal li a:hover {
background:#000000;
text-decoration:none;
color:#ffffff;
}
#backBanner { }
```

Comment: Wow guy... I put all this effort into answering your question and you couldn't give me a vote for it?  Glad I helped you, let me tell ya.